# Inserting Values in FormArray's FormControl and displaying in HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I want to insert Dynamic Values inside my FormArray. My FormGroup Looks like this:

```
    this.createCalcForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  organization_id: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
  section_master_id: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
  description: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
  notes: new FormControl(""),
  status: new FormControl(""),
  data_point1: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
  formula: this.formBuilder.array([]),
});

createItem4(): FormGroup {
return this.formBuilder.group({
  function: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
  data_point2: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
});
```

The Data Format that i am getting from looks like below:-

```
var formula = [
{
    "type": "data",
    "data_point_id": "b164483c-3b11-47c5-926e-643943d8c72c"
},
{
    "type": "operation",
    "value": "*"
},
{
    "type": "data",
    "data_point_id": "a400062a-3281-44f6-bc00-39d690145d84"
},
{
    "type": "operation",
    "value": "-"
},
{
    "type": "data",
    "data_point_id": "e11246cd-70fc-4d9b-b2f9-10a41a288637"
}
```

]

So if type == "data" then data_point_id should be inserted in data_point2 formContorl and if type=="operation" then value should be inserted in function formContorl

```
this.dynamicformats = formula;

  let fArray = this.createCalcForm.controls.formula as FormControl;
  this.dynamicformats.map((value: any) => {
    if (value.type == "data") {
      fArray.value.push({
        function: "",
        data_point2: value.data_point_id,
      });
    } else {
      fArray.value.push({
        function: value.value,
        data_point2: "",
      });
    }
  });
```

this is how i am using it in html:

```
<fieldset formArrayName="formula"
                    >
      <div class="mt-1" *ngFor="let item of createCalcForm.get('formula')['controls']; let i = index;" [formGroup]="item">

        <label for="function">Function</label>
    <select name="function" id="function" class="form-control" formControlName="function"  required (change)="changeSelect2($event, 'operation')">
        <option selected disabled>Select Function</option>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let role of section_key">
            <option value="+">+</option>
            <option value="-">-</option>
            <option value="/">/</option>
            <option value="*">*</option>
        </ng-container>
      </select>
      
        <label for="data_point2">Data Point </label>
    <select name="data_point2" id="data_point2" class="form-control"  formControlName="data_point2" required (change)="changeSelect2($event, 'data')">
        <option selected disabled>Select Data Point</option>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let role of table_info">
            <option [value]="role.id">{{role.key}}</option>
        </ng-container>
      </select>
      </div>

      </fieldset>
```

Values are being set in FormArray but not rendering in HTML.
Can anyone see what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

This is the main cause of your problems.

```
let fArray = this.createCalcForm.controls.formula as FormControl;
  this.dynamicformats.map((value: any) => {
    if (value.type == "data") {
      fArray.value.push({
        function: "",
        data_point2: value.data_point_id,
      });
    } else {
      fArray.value.push({
        function: value.value,
        data_point2: "",
      });
    }
  });
```

This dynamicformats mapping function is adding objects to the value property of fArray. Now with fArray you're referring to a FormControl but as you can see in the createCalcForm formula property is actually a FormArray.

The fArray.value property you're referring to is an array of all the values (of which it has none, since it contains no controls) in the current FormArray; it is not meant to change the values themselves and it can not add new controls. To add new controls you push AbstractControl objects directly to the FormArray.

```
let fArray = this.createCalcForm.controls['formula'] as FormArray;
  this.dynamicformats.map((value: any) => {
    if (value.type == "data") {
      fArray.push(this.createItem4("", value.data_point_id))
    } else {
      fArray.push(this.createItem4(value.value, ""))
    }
  });
createItem4(functionVal: string, data_point2Val:string): any {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
  function: new FormControl(functionVal, [Validators.required]),
  data_point2: new FormControl(data_point2Val, [Validators.required]),
  });
}
```

You're currently not displaying these values anywhere, to do so you can use some property literal interpolation.

```
{{item.controls.function.value}}
```

Now this will get your code working but I'd recommend reading this webpage to get a better overview of a FormArray usecase that's similar to yours: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-form-array/